# Graph embedding to split merged nodes

Tags: deep-learning, 3d, statistics, conv-neural-network, embedding

I really need help from the graph/network experts.

Suppose I have a graph, there is one adjacency matrix, which is 2n*2n, nodes number is 2n. I also have another adjacency matrix, which is n*n matrix. Statistically, the second adjacency matrix is generated from 2n*2n matrix by row and column folding.

This is a toy example of how to generate n*n matrix from 2n*2n matrix.

2n * 2n matrix,n=2:

```
a1a1,a1a2,a1b1,a1b2
a2a1,a2a2,a2b1,a2b2
b1a1,b1a2,b1b1,b1b2
b2a1,b2a2,b2b1,b2b2
```

a1,a2,b1,b2 is four different nodes. Each element is node distance between two nodes in adjacency matrix. eg. a1b2 is the distance between node a1 and b2.

The n*n matrix is generated by row and column folding.

```
a1a1 + a1b1 + b1a1 + b1b1, a1a2 + a1b2 + b1a2 + b1b2
a2a1 + a2b1 + b2a1 + b2b1, a2a2 + a2b2 + b2a2 + b2b2
```

The data I have are 2n*2n and n*n matrix. I know I can use 2n*2n matrix to do graph embedding. But I have this extra n*n matrix as well, which I also want to use during graph embedding.

Can any graph/network experts name some methods or models that can split n*n adjacent matrix into 2n*2n , and combine this newly generated 2n*2n matrix with the original 2n*2n matrix to do graph embedding?

I tried statistical model, it works. I can randomly initial the x,y,z position for each node in 3D, and use MLE to maximize the observed value in 2n*2n and n*n matrix. But statistical model assumes distance between nodes is independent. Graph embedding can preserve node dependence. which could be better for my model.

Comment: Yes, it's adjacency matrix.

Comment: Since I want to do graph embedding, I assume it's related to graph.